# entschuldigung für meine Abwesenheit : do you use this in your email?

Tags: english-to-german, letter

I can't attend my class today and want to write about ym teacher:

> Leider ist es mir aus gesundheitlichen Gründen heute nicht möglich, am Kurs teilzunehmen. Ich bitte Sie, meine Abwesenheit zu entschuldigen.
> Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis.

Do you use in your mails:

> "Ich bitte Sie, meine Abwesenheit zu entschuldigen" ?

and if not, could you please suggest me something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely perfect, only a bit formal. You'll encounter texts like that in native-speaker e-mails.

Using the phrase "aus gesundheitlichen Gründen" tells the reader that you don't want to disclose the nature of these reasons. That's perfectly valid, your health is your private concern, not theirs. You'd more often encounter sentences like "Ich bin leider erkrankt und kann deshalb heute nicht am Kurs teilnehmen.", disclosing a tiny bit more of information.

The sentence you asked about, "Ich bitte Sie meine Abwesenheit zu entschuldigen", doesn't add any new information, it's just politeness, and is sometimes omitted in e-mails.

Comment: "Ich bitte Sie, meine Abwesenheit zu entschuldigen" is absolutely okay and I would not omit it. But imo it is unnecessary to add "Vielen Dank für Ihr Verständnis".

Comment: can i write: _ich schreibe ihnen, um zu fragen, ob ich freinehmen könnte, vordem ich die termine wahrnehme_... do you write in ge smth like this?

Comment: @FrHart64 That would better be a new question.